# Post on Facebook wall using UIActivityVIewController and FBConnect showing in different format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am new for iOS development. Using `FBConnect` i can post message, image, link  and logo image like as shown in the below image . But I can't post using `UIActivityViewController` as show in the image.

Can anyone please help me?

when i use `FBConnect` it is posted like-
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sGZB.png]

and when i use `UIActivityViewController` it is posted like this-
   [image]

Comment: Sorry, i really didn't understand the question..

Comment: If i understand correctly, you were able to post using FBConnect but having some issue while post using UIActivityViewController, right?

Comment: ok, can you post the code?

Comment: Check first link on [this page](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog-tags/ios?page=1) for share using `UIActivityViewController`

Comment: @Bharat I can post using uiactivityviewcontroller. But the display format is different for both fbconnect and uiactivityviewcontroller on fb wall. Can i change that one? This is my question...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `UIActivityViewController`.

You have to use FacebookSDK methods to post details like this.